# Switch html templates dynamically on user action in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

With Angularjs 1.x you could easily switch html templates on a button click between edit/readonly modus. The ng-include directive was the key.

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th></th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="contact in model.contacts" ng-include="getTemplate(contact)">
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The get getTemplate function executes this code:

```javascript
$scope.getTemplate = function (contact) {
    if (contact.id === $scope.model.selected.id) return 'edit';
    else return 'display';
};
```

which again lead to one of those templates to be active in the UI:

**DISPLAY**

```html
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="display">
        <td>{{contact.name}}</td>
        <td>{{contact.age}}</td>
        <td>
            <button ng-click="editContact(contact)">Edit</button>
        </td>
    </script>
```

**EDIT**

```html
<script type="text/ng-template" id="edit">
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="model.selected.name" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="model.selected.age" /></td>
    <td>
        <button ng-click="saveContact($index)">Save</button>
        <button ng-click="reset()">Cancel</button>
    </td>
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/benfosterdev/UWLFJ/

With Angular 2 RC 4 there exist no n-include.

How would I do the same feature just with Angular 2 RC4 ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would leverage `ngTemplateOutlet` directive to do that.

Since version of **2.0.0-rc.2 (2016-06-15)** context was added  to `NgTemplateOutlet`

- https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/164a091

so you can try to use this feature as described in my **[demo plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/5XVqnBETJdW2PYVebOcc?p=preview)** (updated to **4.x.x**)

**template.html**

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th></th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let contact of contacts; let i = index">
            <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="getTemplate(contact)" 
            [ngOutletContext]="{ $implicit: contact, index: i }"></ng-template>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


<ng-template #displayTmpl let-contact>
    <td>{{contact.name}}</td>
    <td>{{contact.age}}</td>
    <td>
        <button (click)="editContact(contact)">Edit</button>
    </td>
</ng-template>

 <ng-template #editTmpl let-i="index">
    <td><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="selected.name" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="selected.age" /></td>
    <td>
        <button (click)="saveContact(i)">Save</button>
        <button (click)="reset()">Cancel</button>
    </td>
</ng-template>
```

**component.ts**

```typescript
import { Component, ViewChild, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';

interface Contact {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    age: number
}

@Component({
    ....
})
export class App {
    @ViewChild('displayTmpl') displayTmpl: TemplateRef<any>;
    @ViewChild('editTmpl') editTmpl: TemplateRef<any>;

    contacts: Array<Contact> = [{
            id: 1,
            name: "Ben",
            age: 28
        }, {
            id: 2,
            name: "Sally",
            age: 24
        }, {
            id: 3,
            name: "John",
            age: 32
        }, {
            id: 4,
            name: "Jane",
            age: 40
        }];

    selected: Contact;

    getTemplate(contact) {
        return this.selected && this.selected.id == contact.id ? 
        this.editTmpl : this.displayTmpl;
    }

    editContact(contact) {
        this.selected = Object.assign({}, contact);
    }

    saveContact (idx) {
        console.log("Saving contact");
        this.contacts[idx] = this.selected;
        this.reset();
    }

    reset() {
        this.selected = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome demo! And the code is very similar to angular 1.X!!! Can you tell me what declaration that is: @ViewChild('editTmpl') editTmpl: TemplateRef<any> , I am doing typescript for some weeks now and I have never seen that syntax.

Comment: It's just access to template inside component class https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/TemplateRef-class.html

Comment: ok thanks. I prefer your solution much over dfsq workaround for angular 2 before RC2 and your implementation for angular RC2+ :-)

Comment: Can you please tell me why you do:      this.selected = Object.assign({}, contact); Why not just do this.selected = contact ? Its because of the two-way binding and the cancel feature right?

Comment: It's a copy of object. Yes its for the right cancel 
behavior. In this case item of array won't change

Comment: Confirmed this still works in Angular 2.2.3. ;) - BTW: Can I use templateUrls thus seperating this into multiple HTML files?

Comment: A little bit of necromancy here just to let you know that this approach also works with with Angular CLI 1.3.x and Angular 4.x.x.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the way you think about this things a little bit. It's not just a template, it's a branch of the application component tree. Think of it in terms of components and what purpose they serve in your application.

In your case, if you have "edit" and "display" views, then it would make sense to design your app with edit and display components and switch them with ngIf or ngSwitch. Each of those components would then need to be able to take data model as a property (`Input`) and render itself the way it needs.

So it could be something like this:

```html
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let contact of model.contacts">
    <contact-display *ngIf="getView(contact) === 'display'" [contact]="contact"></contact-display>
    <contact-edit *ngIf="getView(contact) === 'edit'" [contact]="contact"></contact-edit>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

**UDP**. Here is a simple demo of the approach:

http://plnkr.co/edit/drzI1uL4kkKvsrm0rgOq?p=info

Comment: So you create a component with selector contact-display/contact-edit and a directive [contact]?

Comment: No, you don't need a directive. It's just a component with property contact (or whatever). I will update the answer.

Comment: Check the demo I created of how I would do it.

Comment: After 3 month I must agree with your statement:" it would make sense to design your app with edit and display components" else the wrapper component has 300 lines ;-)

Comment: @dfsq just flagging that your demo doesn't seem to load anymore.