# Component Templating

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm an angular novice, currently building an angular2 app.

What I want to do is generate a series of DOM components from the following object data:

```
// Class construct with alphabeticalized properties
export class Screens {
    screens: Array<Object>;
}


export var screenData: Screens = {
    // Lists all of the audio files in the course 
    screens: [
        {
            id: 0,
            template: 'templateURL-0.html',
            css: 'templateURL-0.css'
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            template: 'templateURL-1.html',
            css: 'templateURL-1.css'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            template: 'templateURL-0.html',
            css: 'templateURL-0.css'
        }
    ]
};
```

I want the end result to be something similar to the following where template 0 will be displayed twice, and template 1 once; in order:

```
<app-screen></app-screen> <!--  templateURL-0.html content  -->
<app-screen></app-screen> <!--  templateURL-1.html content  -->
<app-screen></app-screen> <!--  templateURL-0.html content  -->
```

I read the tutorial on [Structural Directives](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html#!#unless) and I think I need to implement something along those lines, however I'm honestly feeling a little lost on the best approach.

Ideally I would like to have something like:

```
<app-screen *ngFor="let screen of screenData.screens"></app-screen>
```

Which would then somehow set the template URL depending on what `screenData.screens.template` is.

Or should I do something like this? *(unsure if correct syntax)*

```
<div *ngFor="let screen of screenData.screens" [ngSwitch]="screenData.screens.template">
  <app-screen-template1 [ngSwitchCase]="'templateURL-0.html'"></app-screen-template1>
  <app-screen-template2 [ngSwitchCase]="'templateURL-1.html'">Ready</app-screen-template2>
</div>
```

**Note:** I will never change the templateURL reference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic template URLs in Angular 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31692416/dynamic-template-urls-in-angular-2)

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat I was under the impression that question was relating to changing template 'on the fly' not from const data.

Comment: My fault check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38550255/switch-html-templates-dynamically-during-runtime-on-user-action-in-angular-2

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat The second is much closer to my requirements, however I still can't use this answer because (from my understanding) `ngTemplateOutlet` can't be used with URL references.

Comment: Yes but what is stopping you to download that template and supply as a string?

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat Becuase there could be hundreds of components required, each with thousands of lines contained within - would be a coding nightmare and horrible to work with in a team environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the best method to achieve this is to implement routing with the built in `RouterModule`.

So in the end I have the following in my class, where the template property is a url path / url segment.

```
// Class construct with alphabeticalized properties
export class Screens {
    screens: Array<Object>;
}


export var screenData: Screens = {
    // Lists all of the audio files in the course 
    screens: [
        {
            id: 0,
            template: 'template/template-0'
        }
    ]
};
```

Then when I want to load / instantiate this template, all I have to do is navigate to this url using something like:

`<!-- Goes to localhost:4200/template/template-0 -->
<button [routerLink]="[screen.template]"></button>`

Where `screen`is a bound variable in my `.ts`.

More on routing and navigation [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html).