# How to use ng-template across different components

Tags: angular, ng-template

How can I render an `<ng-template>` in different components. Let's say I have component `test` as the following:

test.html

```
<ng-template #content >
   <p> Hello world </p>
</ng-template>
```

test.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'test',
    templateUrl: './test.component.html',
    standalone: true,
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {}
```

Now I want to render it in component `A`. This is what I've tried (and many other more complicated versions that didn't work, so I keep the question with this simplest version):

A.html:

```
<test>
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="content"></ng-container>
</test>
```

The error that I get is :

```
Property 'content' does not exist on type 'AComponent'.
 <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="content"></ng-container>
```

I think this must be very simple to solve but I've checked the guideline in this [post](https://torsten-muller.dev/angular/ng-template-content-injection/), this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46072594/angular-reusable-template), and some other tutorials but none of them worked ...

Comment: turn the `ng-template` into its own component, and render it using its selector, or `<ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="componentRef" />`

Comment: Otherwise, in `test.ts`, you need to get a reference with `@ViewChild('content') content: TemplateRef`. Then in `A.ts` you need to get  a reference to test component which will then give you access to the template.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn can you please explain your second comment a bit more?

Comment: It looks like what your trying to do is pass the template around to random components, and you cannot do that unless it is a component itself (first comment). What you need to do is create an input on `A.ts` that accepts a `TemplateRef`, then pass the template to that input. https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-cshjqt?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Comment: @CodeontheRocks I tried your suggestion, but I am getting an error in `TestComponent.ts` that  `this.content` does not exist in `this.templateService.contentTemplate = this.content;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this is not very common, you can query `TemplateRef` and use it as any other object - pass it as inputs, and share through services as long as an instance of the component that defines the template exists.

The most common scenario is passing `TemplateRef` as input to a child component (it automatically ensures the template exists at the moment the child renders it) which renders it using `NgTemplateOutlet` directive. Here is an example with the use of [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables#prerequisites):

```
// parent template
<ng-template #hello>Hello</ng-template>
<app-child [template]="hello"></app-child>

// child:
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [NgTemplateOutlet],
  template: `<ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="template"></ng-template>`,
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() template?: TemplateRef<any>;
}
```

It is commonly used for implementing customizable components that work together and maintain parent-child relationships e.g. menus, tabs, and tree-views. You can find examples of using `TemplateRef` as input in [Material Tabs](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/api).

---

It is also possible to share it elsewhere as `TemplateRef` can be accessed in the component via `@ViewChild`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-template-definer',
  standalone: true,
  template: `<ng-template>Hello</ng-template>`,
})
export class TemplateDefinerComponent {
  @ViewChild(TemplateRef) template!: TemplateRef<void>;
}
```

From here we can pass it to the child component as input or even can share via service. The latter would be considered an unsafe bad practice and has quite a lot of things to take into consideration before implementing this approach.

Please take a look at [Playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-gyq8bb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fb%2Fb.component.ts) which demonstrates how to share with children and globally.

Comment: They are also very common for `<div *ngIf="condition; then template1; else template2"></div>` pre angular 17.

Comment: @Shlang I tried your first approach, neither I get an error, nor the Hello message is rendered. Regard to your second approach, I'm not sure how the child component gets the template, if the same as previously, i.e., via `<ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="template"></ng-template>` this also doesn't show the hello message.

Comment: @user6781 Have you added `content` input to your `AComponent`? And have you checked the linked playground? It may be better to see how it works altogether.

Comment: @Shlang  I have added content/template like this: `@Input() template!: TemplateRef<any>;` is this correct? Your playground is a bit crowded, I couldn't follow!

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Ensure you imported `NgTemplateOutlet` to the component that uses `[ngTemplateOutlet]`. Other than that everything should work. If you could create a playground I would take a look.

Comment: @Shlang here is my [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ckmwch?file=src%2Ftemplate%2Ftemplate.component.ts), thank you!

Comment: @user6781 well, you don't render TemplateComponent in your AppComponent, you cannot use `template` as a selector as it clashes with the native HTML element name, and you missed the import of `HomeComponent` to `TemplateComponent`. [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ct3z29s) is an updated demo.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257244/discussion-between-user6781-and-shlang).